# Can not SO_REUSEADDR about socket work well in golang?

Tags: go

single IP can only support 65535 port to single destination.
  I hope the client can reuse the old tcp_session immediately during the performance test, even if session is still in time_wait status.

On my Linux machine, I had opened these switch

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
```

Then I write the following code to verify the socket_reuse option with golang.
In the code, I bind the local port 12345.

after run first

```
$go run 1.go

$netstat -nat | grep 12345
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:12345         111.161.3.173:80            TIME_WAIT
```

after run secondary

```
$go run 1.go
Client Connect() called error: cannot assign requested address
```

It seems that the SO_REUSEADDR can not work.
Can Anyone help to resolve this ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    . "syscall"
)

func main() {
    var (
        clientsock int
        serveraddr SockaddrInet4
        err        error
    )

    if clientsock, err = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Client Socket() called error:", err.Error())
        return
    }
    SetsockoptInt(clientsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    defer Shutdown(clientsock, SHUT_RDWR)

    serveraddr.Addr = [4]byte{111, 161, 3, 173}
    serveraddr.Port = 80

    err = Bind(clientsock, &SockaddrInet4{
        Port: 12345,
    })

    if err = Connect(clientsock, &serveraddr); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Client Connect() called error:", err.Error())
        return
   }
}
```

Comment: You're not checking err after Bind

Comment: bind is sucess, and the code can be run without error. if wireshak the pkg, cound find the src_port of SYN will use the bound 12345

Comment: If bind works the `SO_REUSEADDR` is also working, since it only pertains to bind. The go runtime however sets `SO_REUSEADDR` by default, so none of this should be needed. The Linux documentation also says that you should not use `tcp_tw_recycle`

Comment: even if I disable tcp_tw_recycle, the SO_REUSEADDR seems not work as well.

Comment: anyway, my goal is to reuse the source_port which is in TIME_WAIT, any method  satisfied it will be appreciated:)

Comment: Hi Jim, BTW, the go runtime sets SO_REUSEADDR by default only when it is server mode. Now, i want it work on client side

Comment: You don’t use it on the client connection, that’s what tcp_tw_reuse is used for if you’re making connections faster than the TIME_WAIT states time out.

Comment: the similar implement with python will work well for SO_REUSEADDR. just doubt it maybe one bug...

Comment: Since you're making the syscalls yourself here, you can compare the strace from what libc is doing in python to find the difference. In practice though this isn't ever needed and I think you're adding complications that are more likely causing you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to add two changes to your code:

1) Set socket option unix.SO_REUSEPORT.

```
if errReusePort := SetsockoptInt(clientsock, SOL_SOCKET, unix.SO_REUSEPORT, 1); errReusePort != nil {
    fmt.Printf("reuse port error: %v\n", errReusePort)
    return
}
```

2) Make your code to connect to distinct remote TCP endpoints. Otherwise, due to single source addr/port, TCP wouldn't be able to distinguish between two identical connections (protocol, src-addr, src-port, dst-addr, dst-port). The example below specifies two remote server addresses in the command-line.

```
$ go run main.go 127.0.0.1
connected

$ go run main.go 127.0.0.2
connected
```

Find full working code on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/HYLkWlVH6T4

Comment: Sorry response this post so late, After reuse your code and test, it seems that can not resolve this issue as well.
I comment the time.sleep in your code.

Comment: After run two time your code without sleep, the "Client Connect() called error: cannot assign requested address" error still appear.

Comment: @guchao the time.Sleep(10) is in place so that you can manually run multiple concurrent instances. Keep the time.Sleep in place. Run "go run main.go 127.0.0.1" from one terminal and "go run main.go 127.0.0.2" from another. It should work. It works for me every time, I have just tested it again.